# What's up with this website? It came out of nowhere

Tags: discussion, search

3 or 4 months ago I'd never heard of this website. Now all of a sudden it's in the top results in my daily searches like 5x a day. How did it come out of nowhere like that? Am I just losing my mind?

Comment: Once your rep is over `9000`, it will go away.

Comment: Since this (rather surprisingly) hasn't been closed, I'd recommend you head on over to the Meta site (there's a link) and ask the same question.

Comment: @Joe How I love that http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik

Answer (score 3):

SO has been King Of Google for much longer than 3-4 months! But yes, it did rise to the top of SERPs unusually quickly. Possible reasons:

- it's got *loads* of real, unique, massively-cross-linked content. Search engines love this;
- it makes all that information easily accessible without a ton of extraneous markup/scripting or bogus cloaking (unlike That Other Place that used to come top for technical searches);
- the technical nature of the site is particularly suited to keyword searching;
- the reputation system and moderation keeps the worthless clutter down (compared to the unusably noisy general-purpose Q&A sites);
- there are lots of incoming links and relatively few outgoing ones that aren't `nofollow`.

Comment: hey, come visit us on chat.meta !

Answer (score 2):

This is bit of a default answer but probably the simplest answer is to check out the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).  To sum it up it's a Q&A site for programmers by programmers with some extra features to get the "best" answer.